# Passsenger with NGINX cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rubygems, passenger

I have a rails app deployed on debian 7 server, it was working till now.
I deploy code using mina, since my reposiory link has changed, i deleted project and updated repository details and pushed new code to server and restarted nginx.

SInce then i am getting this error:

```
Could not spawn process for application /opt/www/app.co/app: 
An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Error ID: 6d901b8e
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-3HAg6Z.html
Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems   
/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger   
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger 
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I am unable to resolve this load error.

Tried below as mentioned by others, but it didn't help

> gem bundler install && bundle install

My app requires ruby-2.1.5

> rvm list 
>   rvm rubies
>
> =* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

which ruby

> /usr/bin/ruby

In /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf, i have :

> passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
>   passenger_ruby /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/wrappers/ruby;

Tried using default ruby in passenger_ruby as ruby -v gives 1.9.1

> ruby -v
>   ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

But couldn't resolve.

Kindly help me in resolving this as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is being run under a user that you did not expect it to. Could you read [Sandboxing apps with Unix user accounts (user switching)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/user_sandboxing.html) to learn how Passenger runs your app under different users, and see whether you can troubleshoot your issue with this knowledge?